# Subdomain constraint and excluding certain subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `routes.rb` file I want to use the subdomain constraints feature in rails3 however I would like to exclude certain domains from the catch all route. I dont want to have certain controller in a specific subdomain. What would be the best practice in doing so.

```
# this subdomain i dont want all of the catch all routes
constraints :subdomain => "signup" do
  resources :users
end

# here I want to catch all but exclude the "signup" subdomain
constraints :subdomain => /.+/ do
  resources :cars
  resources :stations
end
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your constraint regex to exclude some domains.

```
constrain :subdomain => /^(?!login|signup)(\w+)/ do
  resources :whatever
end
```

Try this out on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/yaGAO9FpD4)

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this technique. I modified it myself to further limit the regex to not match patterns with the first bit and additional characters afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

this is the solution I came to.

```
constrain :subdomain => /^(?!signup\b|api\b)(\w+)/ do
  resources :whatever
end
```

it will match `api` but **not** `apis`

Comment: It does exclude `api` and not `apis` but keep in mind it also would exclude `api-foo`. Using `\Z`(end of string) instead of `\b` (word boundary, as George clearly knows) will no longer exclude `api-foo`. (Of course, it all depends on why you might want to exclude these strings, but more options are better, I figure!)

Answer (score 2):

Revisiting this old question, I just thought of another approach that could work depending on what you want…

The Rails Router tries to match a request to a route in the order specified. If a match is found, the remaining routes are **not** checked. In your reserved subdomain block, you could [glob up all remaining routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) and send the request to an error page.

```
constraints :subdomain => "signup" do
  resources :users
  # if anything else comes through the signup subdomain, the line below catches it
  route "/*glob", :to => "errors#404" 
end

# these are not checked at all if the subdomain is 'signup'
resources :cars
resources :stations
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a negative lookahead as suggested by edgerunner & George is great.

Basically the pattern is going to be:

```
constrain :subdomain => /^(?!signup\Z|api\Z)(\w+)/ do
  resources :whatever
end
```

This is the same as George's suggestion but I changed the `\b` to `\Z` — changing from a word boundary to the end of the input string itself (as noted in my comment on George's answer).

Here are a bunch of test cases showing the difference:

```
irb(main):001:0> re = /^(?!www\b)(\w+)/
=> /^(?!www\b)(\w+)/
irb(main):003:0> re =~ "www"
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> re =~ "wwwi"
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> re =~ "iwwwi"
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> re =~ "ww-i"
=> 0
irb(main):007:0> re =~ "www-x"
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> re2 = /^(?!www\Z)(\w+)/
=> /^(?!www\Z)(\w+)/
irb(main):010:0> re2 =~ "www"
=> nil
irb(main):011:0> re2 =~ "wwwi"
=> 0
irb(main):012:0> re2 =~ "ww"
=> 0
irb(main):013:0> re2 =~ "www-x"
=> 0
```