# How to serve a controller only on a specific subdomain? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a controller `Partners` that I want to server off of `http://partners.example.com`

1. Is there something built into Rails 3.1 that I can use for this **without** messing with `httpd.conf` or creating another virtualhost?
2. What would the routes.rb entry look like for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I'm not doing wildcard subdomains here -- just that one single subdomain.

**UPDATE:** I've gotten the subdomain to work with Ahmish's solution below, but now all other routes also respond on that subdomain. Is there a way I can have the subdomain respond **exclusively** to the controller specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can.

If the PartnersController is a REST based controller, it is as simple as adding a constraints option to the call to `resources`.

```
resources :partners, :constraints => { :subdomain => "partners" }
```

Alternatively, `constraints` can be called with a block, and all routing calls inside the block will be subject to the set subdomain constraint.

```
constraints :subdomain => "partners" do
  resources :partners
  ...
end
```

Requests to the constrained URLs without the correct subdomain will throw a `RoutingError`.

Comment: Is there a way to not have all other routes respond to this subdomain? Since now that same content would get served on two urls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5924503/241212 could be modified to fit, since the subdomain constraint can take a regex. Alternatively you could set the canonical URL to be the non-subdomain URL through the meta tags.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to accomplish this with a routes.rb update. Check out request-based constraints in the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints).

Comment: Would I need to change all the existing routes to have `:constraints => {:subdomain => "www"}` so that their content isn't served from two places?

Comment: I don't think so... I don't remember ever having to.

Comment: I just tried it. The subdomain works but all other routes are also getting served off the subdomain (will be a duplicate content problem with search engines).